# how do you practically send and receive mandrill

Tags: node.js, mandrill

I know how to send email using mandrill api and i know how to read the json data off from webhooks. However, do use mandrill effectively do i need to invent email client.

Is there a way to integrate mandrill to gmail or any other email service/client.. so when i send emails they go via mandrill and when i get email it shows up there.

or like gui for mandrill?

Ideally  this is what should happen

**Someone sends email to support@mycompany.com**

customer@abc.com > support@mycompany.com > mandrill > mandrillmiddle@mandrill.com > my@gmail.com

Then I reply back to it

me > mandrillmiddle@mandrill.com > support@mycompany.com > customer@abc.com

Answer (score 1):

**For Sending:**

Mandrill supports SMTP, so you can use something like [nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) to send emails via mandrill to your customers, visit following link:

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738467-Using-Mandrill-s-SMTP-integration-with-Web-Frameworks

**For Receiving**

To receive mails, you will probably call mandrill rest APIs, there seem to be an official wrapper for it:

https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-node

Hope it helps.

Comment: so i have to basically create email client where i can write emails and send them and then read emails.

Comment: i have thought of different way though it would use more of the limit but it may be sufficient for lot of people and could be overcome with my own smtp sync..Basically make an app act as email router...get email from user > send it to my gmail with dynamic from address > when i reply to that app maps dynamic address back to user's email and then forward him the message. This way i get to use gmail.